# Using ipython magics from inside python modules to be loaded in notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am pretty new to ipython and still learning and liking its functionality. Trying to write a module with common tasks so users of a notebook can load my custom module and save typing common code.

Here is a sample mymodule.ipy:

```
    import mymodule as mymod
    mymod.func():
       wd=%pwd
       return wd
```

When I test it in the notebook:

```
    import mymodule as my
    ---------------
    ImportError        Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-1-1036e4702cf4> in <module>()
    ----> 1 import mymodule as my

    ImportError: No module named mymodule
```

But when I rename the module file as mymodule.py, the module load fails with error message denoting it cannot recognize the pwd magic:

```
    File "mymodule.py", line 2
        wd=%pwd
           ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My question is how do I write a module with ipython magics and other ipython functionality in it which I can load from notebooks? I had the impression that I can put ipython code into a file with .ipy extension and can load it from ipython. Am I missing something?

Comment: I could use the mymodule.ipy by doing a "%run mymodule.ipy" and now the functions in the module is available for using in the notebooks. This servers my need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"%run mymodule.ipy" as pointed in my comment serves my need for now. Posting it as answer to close this question. Feel free to post more if you have a "module" approach.

Comment: Yes, that's the right way to do it. You can't import it, because `.ipy` scripts are just scripts, not modules. But `%pwd` is just shorthand for `os.getcwd()`, so you could use that in a module.